# Is there a way to allow a class to accept the subclass of one of the attribute classes, c++?

Tags: c++

How can I get a class to accept a subclass of the class it ussually accepts as an attribute? This will be important later on as I need a class to accept many different types of classes. Also, `template<>` will not work for later on.
Like this:

```
class A{
   // only used as a parent class
};


class B : A{
   A a;

public:
   B(A a) : a(a) {}
};


class C : A{
   int i;

public:
   C(int i) : i(i) {}
};


int main(){
   C c = C(1);
   B b = B(C);
   return 0;
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
class A{
   virtual ~A() = default;
};


class B : A{
   unique_ptr<A> a;

public:
   B(unique_ptr<A> a) : a(move(a)) {}
};


class C : A{
   int i;

public:
   C(int i) : i(i) {}
};


int main(){
   C c = C(1);
   B b = B(C);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is is intended to inherit **and** have member `A` (So having 2 `A`s) in `B`?

Comment: `class B : A ...` makes `A` a **private** base of `B`, so converting a `B` object to an `A` object is not allowed outside of members of `B`. Change it to `class B : public A ...` to make the inheritance public. Or change it to `struct B : A ...` which also makes the inheritance public.

Answer (score 0):

The definition

```
B b = B(C);
```

have two problems:

1. You pass the `C` *class* to the `B` constructor, not the object. A class is like a type. It's like doing `C c = C(int)` (with your `C` class).
2. The second problem is that the `B` class stores an `A` object, it can't store a `C` object. When you attempt to store the `C` object you will have *object slicing*, where you loose the `C` parts of the object.

One possible solution is to store a *reference* in the `B` class:

```
class B
{
    A& a;

public:
    B(A& a) : a{a}
    {
    }
};

// ...

B b(c);  // Use the c object

// ...
```

Also note that the above code has dropped the inheritance, because there's just no reason for `B` to inherit from `A`.

---

Your second attempt, with the pointers still have the problem of you trying to pass a class as an argument to the `B` constructor. It also have the problem that the object `c` is not a pointer, much less a `std::unique_ptr<A>`, and can't be passed as an argument.

With your current design I recommend using references, as shown above, instead of pointers.